# Minimum-cost stack of "connected" cubes

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, discrete-geometry

We have a stack of $n \times n \times n$ cubes, each with a possibly negative cost.
You are allowed to remove cubes from the stack, but each remaining cube must have

1. a cube immediately below it,
2. a cube immediately to the left of it, and
3. a cube immediately "inside" of it (or whatever you call the third dimension).

Of course, Condition 1 does not apply to the bottom layer etc.
[Below is an example](http://reed.cs.depaul.edu/lperkovic/Fall13/stacks/stacks.html) that we can think of as a sub-stack of an original stack of $6 \times 6 \times 6$ cubes.

**Which cubes should be removed from the stack to find a minimum-cost sub-stack?**
The two-dimensional case can be solved as a simple shortest path in a graph, but I cannot see how to solve this three-dimensional problem in an efficient way.

[image: Example]

Comment: This appears at first glance to be an ideal situation for dynamic programming (which will probably still take cubic or quartic time). Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks for the comment: No, I have not, I'll look into that. Also, cubic in n? Anything below n^6 is interesting!

Comment: The algorithmic aspects will sooner or later have to be connected with certain data structures (in the spirit of Dijkstra) : the mathematical data structures which are the most natural here are known as "Young tableaux" under their standard form : see  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau).

Comment: I should have said "not-too-high-degree-polynomial in n," **but** it might be of high degree in the range of "costs" for the cubes (or the sum of those costs). Look at a stock solution for the knapsack problem to see why.

Comment: Generally, each cost will be in $[-1,1]$ and no two the same, so $n^3$ different values. The issue is then that there won't be much overlap between the subproblems for the dynamic programming approach?

Comment: The question looks to be a duplicate of your [former question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2555732/least-weight-comprehensive-set-easy-in-two-dimensions-what-about-three).